# how to avoid native player when playing html5 video in phonegap/cordova app?

Tags: html, cordova

how to avoid launching native video player on iphone when playing html5 video , using phonegap/cordova .

i added  `<video data-id="1" webkit-playsinline>` to the video tag.

and i added this preference to the config.xml at the root of the project . 
`<preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="true" />`

it worked fine on the emulator but when i tested the project on the iphone 5

edit : hey swennemen,  thanks for replying,  i have one more question
does the video also launch the native player when on landscape screen orientation or does it load correctly in that case ?.